# a SSRS 2008 problem:How to increase the response time

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created a report using ssrs 2008.i have used mutiple times of grouping of data.Problem is arise when i preview the report it takes a lot of time ,sometimes more than 40 minutes.
how can i resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can cache the dataset, [Microsoft recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx) to cache the dataset when the time taken is more then what is expected.

Also read the link http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/a-performance-troubleshooting-methodology-for-sql-server/ which provides the basis for troubleshooting the Query at the database level.